# Sending a Facebook private message within app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

I already have an active Facebook session in my app, and want to be able to send a private message to a friend using the access token I already have. The closest I've gotten is to open a UIWebview to the touch interface, but the user will need to log into Facebook again before being able to send a message.  Is there a way to send a private message using the session that is already active, and ideally, using my own interface?  If I could send an email to the username@facebook.com programmatically, that would be perfect, but that isn't possible in iOS that I know of.

As I understand it, here are the options to send messages to friends in iOS:

1. Send an email using the mail composer to the username@facebook.com (unable to send email programmatically, otherwise this will be perfect)
2. Send an app request/post on the wall using the Facebook SDK
3. Open a webview (and log into Facebook again) show the touch dialog for messaging

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that you can send private Facebook messages using the Facebook Chat API using XMPP.

https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework

Quickblox has some sample code that demonstrates how to send FB messages.